# How to export .pdf as new file instead of fixed file name and fixed file directory?

Tags: vb.net

I have problem finding a video that tells me how to export .PDF as new file instead of having a fixed name and fixed file directory. Can you please help me? Just a new programmer here.

Here is the code:

```
 'Exporting to PDF
    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\PDFs\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
    Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "DataGrid.pdf", FileMode.Create)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        stream.Close()
        End Using
```

Comment: How do you want to tell the program where you want to store the file and with which filename?

Comment: I want the 'Save as' to appear once I click the button. Meaning I can choose where to save it to.

Comment: Please do not [shout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting)

Comment: @OcasoProtal I am not :(

Comment: No problem, I edited your headline ;)

Comment: So you want to display a `SaveFileDialog`?  Go right ahead.  It's right there in the Toolbox.  This is why you should take the time to look in places like the Toolbox and the Options dialogue: to see what's available.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-save-files-using-the-savefiledialog-component

Comment: @AljonDavid Also have a look at [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) to create file paths from different parts, it's a bit safer than just concatenating the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the name of the new PDF file, if you just want to do an incremental export (PDF_1, PDF_2) you can use an int variable then convert it to a str and concatenate it to the filepath.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to convert it to a string. Just started vb a few weeks ago :(

Comment: @AljonDavid ~ You can convert an `Integer` to a `String` using something like this: `Dim sText As String = "PDF_"` `Dim iNumber As Integer = 5` `sText &= CStr(iNumber)`